# converting the MS Office document to Swf using command line arrgument?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ms-office

hi i am trying to convert the MS Office files to swf so that i am able to load them to flex air application. is there open source tool that provide a command line interface for converting a MS Office file to swf, currently i am converting them to pdf and them making the swf but the problem is after this i got the pdf as well as swf with different formatting or text tables etc. in some cases.

need help .

regards

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to reach?

- Do need to display MS Office Documents inside of a Flex application?
- Do you want to edit MS Office Documents?

In case you want to display them, **why not stick to PDFs**?

For he SWF way, I found this solution, but never used it myself:

http://www.brothersoft.com/swf-printer-291607.html

Additionally, Adobe Cookbook has a bunch of threads:

- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/search/pdf?hl=en_US
- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_PDF_2_SWF_Conversion-4701.html